# TinyMCE: How do I prevent `<br data-mce-bogus="1">` text in editor?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a page with several TinyMCE (v4) editors, which all work great ... until I try and add:

```
inline: true
```

to their configuration.  When I do that the inline-ing part works great (the toolbar is gone, then appears when I focus the editor), but for some strange reason the editor stops working at that point.  Inside the editor I see:

```
<br data-mce-bogus="1">
```

but I can't edit that text, or add new text, or do anything at all really with the editor.

I can make the editor work again if I remove `inline: true`, but I really want the inline effect.  Does anyone have any idea how I can get `inline` without breaking my editors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently had this problem, `inline: true` would not work with a textarea. I change mine to a div and it now works as expected.

Comment: It's been awhile since I had this issue, but I think that turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, the "bogus" br tags appear for inline divs, too. They are added whenever the input field is empty. There appears to be no easy way to get rid of them. I use a CSS rule during the preview phase:

```
br[data-mce-bogus="1"] {
  display:none;
}
```

And then strip them out if they make it to the server when the user tries to save.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the tinymce jQuery package? The same thing was happening to me until I tried using the normal tinymce package instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm already using the non-jQuery version of TinyMCE (and switching to the jQuery version doesn't help either).

Comment: I can confirm that this behavior can be observed using jQuery version of TinyMCE, but not with the "classic" version.
For example, try to insert several bullets *with Firefox*. First with http://archive.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php . Then with http://archive.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_version.php .
Using the developper console you'll see that <br data-mce-bogus="1"> is added to each li item in the editor when using jQuery version.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong. I found out the difference between the two configurations : "lists" plugin is missing in the jQuery page. If "lists" plugin has not been configured, but bullets are used, it lead to insertion of <br data-mce-bogus="1">.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#comment").ready(function () {
        $("#comment").val("")
    })

})
</script>
```

I add this jquery script in html to solve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet to your CSS file. That would prevent video bogus.

```
[data-mce-bogus="all"] {
  display:none;
}
```